# Store the output of a loop inside a function into a vector or data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame `df` that looks like the following:

```
structure(list(sequence = c("CSPPPPSPSPHPRPP", "GEGSPTSPTSPKQPG", 
"EAGAPAGSGAPPPAD", "PAPPKPKESKEPENA", "AKPKQQDEDPDGAAE", "GDRGGGTGNEDDDYE"
), group = c("BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP")), .Names = c("sequence", 
"group"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

For all the character variables under`df$sequence` I want to get all the possible sub-sets of 7 characters, shifting one character to the right after each iteration.
For that, I created a function called `scan_core_OLpeptides`. If I apply the following function:

```
scan_core_OLpeptides <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_len(nchar(x)-7+1)){
    print(str_sub(string = x, start = i, end = i+6))
}}
```

I get the following output:

```
[1] "CSPPPPS" "GEGSPTS" "EAGAPAG" "PAPPKPK" "AKPKQQD" "GDRGGGT"
[1] "SPPPPSP" "EGSPTSP" "AGAPAGS" "APPKPKE" "KPKQQDE" "DRGGGTG"
[1] "PPPPSPS" "GSPTSPT" "GAPAGSG" "PPKPKES" "PKQQDED" "RGGGTGN"
[1] "PPPSPSP" "SPTSPTS" "APAGSGA" "PKPKESK" "KQQDEDP" "GGGTGNE"
[1] "PPSPSPH" "PTSPTSP" "PAGSGAP" "KPKESKE" "QQDEDPD" "GGTGNED"
[1] "PSPSPHP" "TSPTSPK" "AGSGAPP" "PKESKEP" "QDEDPDG" "GTGNEDD"
[1] "SPSPHPR" "SPTSPKQ" "GSGAPPP" "KESKEPE" "DEDPDGA" "TGNEDDD"
[1] "PSPHPRP" "PTSPKQP" "SGAPPPA" "ESKEPEN" "EDPDGAA" "GNEDDDY"
[1] "SPHPRPP" "TSPKQPG" "GAPPPAD" "SKEPENA" "DPDGAAE" "NEDDDYE"
```

Which is exactly what I want. However, I wanted to store this output into an object, preferably into a vector or into a data.frame.
I thought about storing into a list but it did not work.

Comment: You can use `apply` to get it int to an object or create an object in for loop and pass the output to that

Comment: I tried to create the object and store each iteration into it, yet it did not work.

Comment: Please check the solution I posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'd use `zoo` package for this,

```
library(zoo)
sapply(strsplit(df1$sequence, ''), function(i) rollapply(i, 7, by = 1, 
                                                   function(i)paste0(i, collapse = '')))
```

Comment: Note that this can also be written as: `sapply(strsplit(df1$sequence, ''), rollapply, 7, paste, collapse = '')`

Answer (score 1):

We can modify the function to create a `list` to store the output that comes from each 'i'

```
scan_core_OLpeptides <- function(x) {
  x1 <-  vector("list", nrow(df))
  for(i in seq(nchar(x) - 7 +1) ){
   x1[[i]] <- str_sub(string = x, start = i, end = i+6)

  }
   x1
}  


scan_core_OLpeptides(df$sequence)
#[[1]]
#[1] "CSPPPPS" "GEGSPTS" "EAGAPAG" "PAPPKPK" "AKPKQQD" "GDRGGGT"

#[[2]]
#[1] "SPPPPSP" "EGSPTSP" "AGAPAGS" "APPKPKE" "KPKQQDE" "DRGGGTG"

#[[3]]
#[1] "PPPPSPS" "GSPTSPT" "GAPAGSG" "PPKPKES" "PKQQDED" "RGGGTGN"

#[[4]]
#[1] "PPPSPSP" "SPTSPTS" "APAGSGA" "PKPKESK" "KQQDEDP" "GGGTGNE"

#[[5]]
#[1] "PPSPSPH" "PTSPTSP" "PAGSGAP" "KPKESKE" "QQDEDPD" "GGTGNED"

#[[6]]
#[1] "PSPSPHP" "TSPTSPK" "AGSGAPP" "PKESKEP" "QDEDPDG" "GTGNEDD"
```